# How to validate values in an object array which have duplicate IDs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an object array which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "type":"Greater than",
        "value":"5"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "type":"Less than",
        "value":"29"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "type":"Less than",
        "value":"40"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "type":"Greater than",
        "value":"50"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "type":"Less than",
        "value":"10"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "type":"name",
        "value":"Anna"
    }
]
```

I would like to do some validation and return true if all the *greater than/less than* for each ID is correct.

For example, the above should return false because ID 3 has a greater than value larger than the less than value (even though ID 1 is correct).

Not all IDs will have both a greater than and less than (see ID 2 and ID 4)

I've been trying different ways but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Hi! Please see [mcve] and [ask], since "I've been trying different ways but can't seem to find a solution" you could show us what you've tried so we can help.

Comment: I've tried using Array.find but the problem is fetching all the matching IDs and then checking their range values. Not all ID's have a pair @Wyck

Comment: This is going to give some people twitches because `id` is usually a unique field.  If it's the id of something *else*, like the id of a related field, then maybe call it `key` or something, so we know it's not supposed to be unique.  Even then, it's worth calling out that this is a multi-map (where each key can have multiple values).

Comment: You have three problems 1) locate the applicable objects in the array (use Array.filter for this), 2) Test if all filtered conditions apply (Array.every on the filtered results) and 3) Make the object with properties `"type":"Greater than", "value":"5"` refer to a function that performs the check `(input) => input > 5` and apply it to the input.  So which of those 3 is your actual problem?

Comment: How is is `{ "id":4, "type":"name", "value":"Anna" }` supposed to be validated?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const ids = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Greater than",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Less than",
    "value": "29"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "Less than",
    "value": "40"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "Greater than",
    "value": "50"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "Less than",
    "value": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "type": "name",
    "value": "Anna"
  }
]

function check(array) {
  const min = new Map() // Greater than [1->5, 3->50]
  const max = new Map() //    Less than [1->29,3->10]
  for (let { id, type, value } of array) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'Less than':
        //                             > or >=
        if (min.has(id) && min.get(id) > +value) {
          return false
        }
        max.set(id, +value)
        break
      case 'Greater than':
        if (max.has(id) && max.get(id) < +value) {
          return false
        }
        min.set(id, +value)
        break
    }
  }
  return true
}

console.log(
  check(ids)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isValidRange = ([start, end]) =>
  start <= end

function check(arr) {
  const map = new Map();
  
  for (const item of arr) {
    const [start, end] = map.get(item.id) ?? [-Infinity, Infinity];
    
    const value = Number(item.value);
    
    let newRange;
    switch (item.type) {
      case "Greater than":
        newRange = [Math.max(start, value), end];
        break;
      case "Less than":
        newRange = [start, Math.min(value, end)];
        break;
    }
    
    if (!isValidRange(newRange))
      return false;

    map.set(item.id, newRange);
  }
  
  return true;
}


const invalid = [ 
  { "id": 1, "type": "Greater than", "value": "5"  }, 
  { "id": 1, "type": "Less than"   , "value": "29" }, 
  { "id": 2, "type": "Less than"   , "value": "40" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Greater than", "value": "50" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Less than"   , "value": "10" } 
]

const valid = [ 
  { "id": 1, "type": "Greater than", "value": "5"  }, 
  { "id": 1, "type": "Less than"   , "value": "29" }, 
  { "id": 2, "type": "Less than"   , "value": "40" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Greater than", "value": "50" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Greater than", "value": "51" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Greater than", "value": "25" }, 
  { "id": 3, "type": "Greater than", "value": "52" }, 
]

console.log(check(invalid));
console.log(check(valid));
```

1. Convert the objects to a range representational (a pair of start and end values):

   - `{ "type": "Greater than", "value": "5" }` converts to the range [5, Infinity]`
   - `{ "type": "Less than", "value": "29" }` converts to the range `[-Infinity, 29]`
2. For items with the same `id`, combine the ranges by picking the highest of the start values and the lowest of the end values. The above two will combine to create `[5, 29]`.
3. Every time a range is to be combined with another, check if the new range is valid. Combining `[50, Infinity]` and `[-Infinity, 10]` produces `[50, 10]` which is wrong.
4. If any range is invalid, return `false`.
5. If all ranges are valid, return `true`.

Answer (score -1):

The array method `every()` will come in handy here.

In my example below, I added support for an "Equal to" property as well, and I check all the objects contained in a single array and ensure they are all valid, ignoring any string-types like `type: "name", value: "Anna"`.

Check it out:

```js
const data1 = [
  { id: 1, type: "Greater than", value: "5" },
  { id: 1, type: "Less than", value: "29" },
  { id: 2, type: "Less than", value: "40" },
];

const data2 = [
  { id: 3, type: "Greater than", value: "1" },
  { id: 3, type: "Equal to", value: "3" },
  { id: 4, type: "name", value: "Anna" }
];

const validate = data => data.every(({ id: a, value: b, type: t }) => !["Greater than", "Less than", "Equal to"].includes(t) || ((b = +b), ((t === "Greater than" && (a > b)) || (t === "Less than" && (a < b)) || (t === "Equal to" && (a === b)))));

console.log(validate(data1));
console.log(validate(data2));
```

And if you don't mind some type coercion between strings and numbers, we can trim off the entire `(b = +b)` part and use double equals `==` for that last "Equal to" comparison, making the code reasonably shorter. Either way, we are converting a string to a number, and it doesn't appear to make a big performance difference if we do that before comparing or while comparing:

```js
const data1 = [
  { id: 1, type: "Greater than", value: "5" },
  { id: 1, type: "Less than", value: "29" },
  { id: 2, type: "Less than", value: "40" },
];

const data2 = [
  { id: 3, type: "Greater than", value: "1" },
  { id: 3, type: "Equal to", value: "3" },
  { id: 4, type: "name", value: "Anna" }
];

const validate = data => data.every(({ id: a, value: b, type: t }) => !["Greater than", "Less than", "Equal to"].includes(t) || ((t === "Greater than" && (a > b)) || (t === "Less than" && (a < b)) || (t === "Equal to" && (a == b))));

console.log(validate(data1));
console.log(validate(data2));
```

Comment: @user14374853 I've updated my solution to use object destructuring and renaming to make the logic simpler overall. Instead of evaluating `x.id > +x.value` we can just evaluate `a > b`

Comment: [Neither of the two seems to correctly validate the objects](https://jsbin.com/tuvikel/1/edit?js,console). You're never actually checking the object against any other object just against itself. And I'm not really sure why you're comparing the ID with the value.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, judging by the question, I believe that is exactly what is being asked. Each object, in most cases, is being evaluated to see if its `id` is greater than or less than its `value`. Please take another look at the question and let me know if I'm misunderstanding the ask here, but the other answers appear to be doing that as well.

Comment: No, it isn't. The ID just links rules together. OP clearly says "*the above should return false because ID 3 has a greater than value larger than the less than value (even though ID 1 is correct)*" thus it's ID 3 is the problem because the boundaries conflict. And it's directly stated that ID 1 is correct. I cannot see how `{ "id":1, "type":"Greater than", "value":"5" }` holds up to your logic - `1` is clearly ***not*** greater than `5`.

Comment: @VLAZ correct, which is why `data1` returns false. This entire post is about validation. `false` is a perfectly acceptable return value here.

Comment: @VLAZ I would add that Alexander Lonberg's answer performs the exact same logic and is currently the only answer with a positive vote count.

Comment: Check `valid1` in the JSBin. It's just the ID 1 objects and they are supposed to be OK. Still returns `false` for them

Comment: Alexander Lonberg's code combines the rules related by ID. It doesn't check if the ID is greater or less than a value. [See how it behaves with `valid1`, `valid2`, and `valid3`](https://jsbin.com/bedapiz/1/edit?js,console)